# JavaScript files not found in vaadin project

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, vaadin, vaadin7

I have problem with accessing javascript files in vaadin project. I get error message:

```
Could not initialize JavaScriptConnector because no JavaScript init function was found.
```

See attached screenshot:

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong name of javascript function in graph_connector.js "socialgraphuibasic" have to be instead of "socialuibasic"